# Excel-Dna Volatile Functions in Massive Updating Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel-addins, excel-dna

I have created an Add-In using Excel-Dna and marked the exported functions as Volatile (IsVolatile=true) which gives me the desired behavior. Functions make use of simple queries to retrieve data from a SQL Server instance.

However, in a particular case of a spreadsheet with hundreds of cells linked to external sources, the recalculation usually freezes the Excel instance.

Although I would like to keep the Volatile feature, it would be useful if I could skip the function recalculation if, for instance, input parameters are the same and the last call was made in a tiny time interval. Not sure if this is advisable, but I am trying to workaround to avoid IsVolatile=False.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a cache inside your add-in which stores the last values returned and a time last checked, using something like  [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). You can also consider figuring out whether you can make the functions thread-safe. Volatile is generally a bad idea though - if the back-end data changes often you need a real-time feed - see the series of [Excel-DNA RTD examples](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Samples/tree/master/RtdClocks). That could help you get rid of volatile, but still update the data regularly (when changed).

Comment: yes avoid Volatile functions if possible. I don't have any volatile functions apart from one which is called MakeVolatile() so that if i really need volatile behaviour i can just wrap the function in the Volatile wrapper  =MakeVolatile(MyNonVolFunction())